# UIActionSheet only showing once

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiactionsheet, uicollectionview

I have the following code which produces a UICollectionView.  When you longpress on a UICollectionViewCell, a UIActionSheet appears.

This works, but only once. If you dismiss the UIActionSheet and longpress the same cell again, nothing happens.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
#import "ProjectsListViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface ProjectsListViewController ()

@end

@implementation ProjectsListViewController

@synthesize appDelegate;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    // CREATE THE COLLECTION VIEW
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];

    [self setCollectionView:[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 54, [[self view] bounds].size.width - 40, [[self view] bounds].size.height) collectionViewLayout:flowLayout]];
    [[self collectionView] setDataSource:self];
    [[self collectionView] setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:self.collectionView];
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    [[self collectionView] setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[appDelegate userSettingsDictionary] objectForKey:@"Projects"] count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView 
{
    return 1;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // CREATE A BACKGROUND VIEW FOR THE FOLDER IMAGE
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"folder.png"]];
    UIView *background = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 122, 89)];
    [background setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image]];
    [cell addSubview:background];

    // SET THE CELL TEXT
    UILabel *cellLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 95, 130, 100)];
    [cellLabel setText:[[[[[appDelegate userSettingsDictionary] objectForKey:@"Projects"] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:@"Project Name"] uppercaseString]];

    // LISTEN FOR A LONG PRESS ON EACH FOLDER
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:longPress];

    [cell addSubview:cellLabel];
    return cell;
}

// PRESENT AN ACTION SHEET WHEN A FOLDER HAS RECEIVED A LONG PRESS EVENT
- (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if ( [recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan )
    {
        UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select an action" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete" otherButtonTitles:@"Edit", nil];

        [actionSheet addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

        // SET THE SELECTED FOLDER'S ROW NUMBER AS THE ACTIONSHEET TAG.  JUST A WAY OF LETTING THE DELETE METHOD KNOW WHICH FOLDER TO DELETE
        [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
    } 
}

// GET THE SIZE OF THE FOLDER IMAGE AND SET EACH COLLECTION VIEW ITEM SIZE TO FIT
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"folder.png"]];
    return CGSizeMake(image.size.width, image.size.height + 50);
}


- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 90, 10);
}

@end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually tried something similar a while ago, and figured out that almost the whole approach was wrong.

To start with: The way you set up your cells isn't good. Because cells are reusable, but now you add the subviews each time the collection view asks for a specific cell. You should subclass `UICollectionViewCell` and add subviews in the `initWithCoder:` method.

Then just create a property on the subclass for the text field. Then in the `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` you just set the text to the labels `text` property.

Now let's fix the gesture recognizer. You shouldn't set a gesture recognizer for each `UICollectionViewCell`, but just one global one. In `viewDidLoad:` you should add:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
[self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
```

Then you should change the `handleLongPress:` to something like this:

```
- (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:[gesture locationInView:self.collectionView]];

        if (indexPath != nil) {
            self.currentIndexPath = indexPath;

            UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select an action" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete" otherButtonTitles:@"Edit", nil];

            UICollectionViewCell *itemCell = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            [action showFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, itemCell.frame.size.width, itemCell.frame.size.height) inView:itemCell animated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I didn't add the line for adding the recognizer to the action sheet, I don't get why you should do that. And you should also add a property named `currentIndexPath`.

Everything should be set up right at this moment. When you get an response from your action sheet, just use the `self.currentIndexPath` to identify which item to delete/edit.

Comment: What a great reply. That fixed my problem, and a couple of others I was having.  Many thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

In `handleLongPress:` you assign the gesture recognizer to the action sheet.

```
[actionSheet addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

I don't know why you do that, but a gesture recognizer can only be used with a single view. This assignment probably removes the gesture recognizer from the table view cell, so that a long press gesture on the table cell does not work anymore.